# Properties of ellipses and hyperbola related to matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

> $5x^2+8xy+5y^2=\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}=
> > (S^T\mathbf{x})^TD(S^T\mathbf{x})=1\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+9\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$
>   Thus, the equation is that of an ellipse, since it is the sum of two
>   squares. It is tempting to simplify this expression by pulling out
>   factors of 2. However, it is important not to do this. **The quantities
>   $c_1=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}},\quad c_2=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$ have a
>   geometrical meaning. They determine an orthonormal coordinate system
>   on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, they are obtained from the original
>   coordinates by the application of a rotation (and possibly a
>   reflection). Consequently, one may use the $c_1$ and $c_2$ coordinates
>   to make statements about length and angles (particularly length),
>   which would otherwise be more difficult in a different choice of
>   coordinates (by rescaling them, for instance). For example, the
>   maximum distance from the origin on the ellipse ${c_1}^2 + 9{c_2}^2 =
> > 1$ occurs when $c_2=0$, so at the points $c1=±1$. Similarly, the
>   minimum distance is where $c_2=±1/3$**. (Wikipedia, Principal Axis Theorem)

I am not getting the bold parts. Can anyone explain this? I do understand the parts before the bold ones.

Thanks.

Edit: I do know that this is an ellipse. What I am not sure of is what it means by $c_1$ and $c_2$ being used to determine orthonormal coordinates. (I also do know what orthonormal means, as it appears in elementary linear algebra.)

More specifically, what is "original coordinates", and what rotation + reflection is occuring due to $c_1$ and $c_2$? What would be the center?

Comment: Please get some graph paper and a calculator and draw a very careful picture of $$ 5 x^2 + 8 x y + 5 y^2 = 18.$$ Given a decimal value for $x,$ you can find the two values of $y$ by the quadratic formula, as long as $|x|$ is not too large. The curve is an ellipse. I could explain this very easily in person...I see, this is from wikipedia, you do not necessarily have the background for this. Well, draw the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by verifying that the matrix

$$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}5&4\\4&5\end{pmatrix}$$

corresponding to your conic $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf A\mathbf x=5x^2+8xy+5y^2=1$, where $\mathbf x^\top=(x\quad y)^\top$ is the vector of variables possesses the following *eigendecomposition*:

$$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}5&4\\4&5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}&-\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\\\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}&\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}9&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}&-\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\\\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}&\tfrac1{\sqrt 2}\end{pmatrix}^\top=\mathbf S\mathbf D\mathbf S^\top$$

Note that the orthogonal matrix $\mathbf S$ is in fact the $45^\circ$ rotation matrix, and that in fact tells you how you obtain the coordinate system $(c_1,c_2)$ from the starting coordinate system $(x,y)$. Since it's easier to analyze an ellipse for, e.g., its principal axes, when the ellipse's two axes coincide with coordinate axes, you can think of it this way: you start with a sketch of a tilted ellipse, and to ease the task of "looking" at the ellipse, you tilt the paper it's drawn on by $45^\circ$, since it's easier to "look" at when the relevant axes are horizontal and vertical.